# How do I set a progress bar in my app for a file transfer

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using file transfer to upload files. How do I add a progress bar to my app. Also, when I send multiple files, how can I get an UI that some upload is been carried out.

This is my code:

```
import { Transfer } from 'ionic-native';

fileTransfer.onprogress(progressEvent) {
    console.log(progressEvent);
    console.log(progressEvent.loaded); //Loaded bytes
    console.log(progressEvent.total); //Total bytes
    console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable); //TRUE if the destination server informs total file length
 };                           

 fileTransfer.upload(file_path, api_endpoint, options, data)
     .then((data) => {
        // success                                                 
        console.log("success", data)
      }, (err) => {
         // error 
         this.failed_upload();
         console.log('File failed uploaded.', err);
     })
```

When i use the above i get err  `cannot find progresssEven` how do i solve it

Ionic has `onProgress(Listener)` method, but, I don't know how to use this method and get value in percentages and bind that value to a spinner.

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) plugin's Readme entirely. Especially [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#example-with-upload-headers-and-progress-events-android-and-ios-only) part?

Comment: ya but i could not understand that, and could not get how to implement it